# How to print the subtasks belonging to specific tasks in Laravel Blade

Tags: php, database, database-design, laravel-5, laravel-blade

This is really difficult for me to wrap my head around, so please excuse me if I don't give a good enough explanation of the situation.

I have a table "tasks", and the only column that I'm really using for this problem is `| tasks_id |`.

I created another table "subtasks", and it has these relevant columns:

`| subtasks_id | subtasks_title | subtasks_tasks_id |`

For each row in the table "tasks", there are `n` rows of subtasks with a different `subtasks_id` but the same `subtasks_tasks_id`.

I print the `tasks` by passing them to an array in my HomeController and looping through the array in the blade template. For every TASK, how would I also loop every SUBTASK, which has the same `subtasks_tasks_id` and the tasks' `tasks_id`?

Is there a way to use the `->where()` clause in the blade template? I'm quite new to Laravel, also I didn't know how to word this into a google search so please do forgive my ignorance. Thank you in advanced.

P.S. I will keep on trying to solve this unless someone gives me an answer beforehand, if I do solve it I will post my answer, if not, please don't hesitate trying to help me :P, thank you again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out what I had to do...

Using a multidimensional array, I can set the key to array `$subtasks` the `| tasks_id |` of any existing subtasks, then the value of each will be a corresponding array where the `subtasks_tasks_id` is the same as the key of the value. I then loop through each subtask by doing something like `$subtask[$tasks_id][$i]` where I create two outer loops (one is already created, so it shouldn't be too difficult). And now I know what to do, next step is the how, or really the actual coding, okay, that is all..